# Understanding $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ as a subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Say that we have a rotation matrix $A \in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$. I can easily visualize this as rotating a plane. However, since $GL(2,\mathbb{R}) \leq GL(2,\mathbb{C})$, we also have that  $A \in GL(2,\mathbb{C})$. So, $A$ is then fixing the imaginary parts of a 2 dimensional complex vector space and rotating the real part? I guess this is just hard for me to think of because I can't visualize it.

In general, does anyone have tips for understanding $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ as a subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})?$ Thanks

Comment: It's rotating both the real part and the imaginary part. If you have $v \in \Bbb C^2$, you can write it as $v = x + iy$ with $x, y \in \Bbb R^2$ and then $A$ acts as $A(x + iy) = Ax + iAy$, i.e. real part = $A \cdot$ real part and imaginary part = $A \cdot $imaginary part.

Comment: Interesting. Then, what kind of matrices are included in $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ that arn't in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$?